# Open help dialog without 'Control Parent' in .net

Tags: c#, .net, null, windows-forms-designer

I would like to open the help dialog. I'm using this call:

```
public static void ShowHelp(Control parent, string url);
```

I'm launching it through a class that doesn't have access to the main control. So I'm passing null as the parent. It does seems to work but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

what does this "parent" argument stands for? what does .net do with it?

Is it safe to pass null as this argument?

I did notice in .Net source code this switch:

```
if (parent != null) {
            handle = new HandleRef(parent, parent.Handle);
        }
        else {
            handle = new HandleRef(null, UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow());
        }
```

Does it safe that it's using the "UnsafeNativeMethods" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Parent control determines which window will own the dialog. If the parent is not a window, the ultimate parent (which should be a window) of this control will be used. If the parent parameter is null, the main window of the process will be chosen (if there is one).

This is needed so that the dialog can be modal and interaction with the parent window is blocked until the dialog has been dismissed.

Comment: FWIW, [Here's the code that does this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Help.cs,314).

Comment: Thanks, does it safe that its using the "UnsafeNativeMethods"?
I edit the main post.

Comment: UnsafeNativeMethods does what it says on the tin: issues 'unsafe' calls to native methods. You are running a winforms project so your binaries are not 'pure' and can indeed contain 'unsafe' (as in: unmanaged) calls. 

Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain ;)